# Getting NULL as XML response for SQL Query in Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named `ListItem` and another table `ListItemRelationship` which holds the many-to-many relationship between the items in the `ListItem` table.

Example: `ListItem` table, `ListItemGroupID` is used to provide one-to-many relationship.

| ListItemID | ListItemCode | Value | ListItemGroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2925 | Currency | EURO | NULL |
| 2926 | State | Washington | NULL |
| 2927 | City | Seattle | 2926 |
| 2930 | City | Spokane | 2926 |
| 2928 | Country | Germany | NULL |
| 2929 | Country | France | NULL |

Example `ListItemRelationship` table this table is to just maintain many-to-many relationship

| ListItemParentID | ListItemID |
| --- | --- |
| 2925 | 2928 |
| 2925 | 2929 |

Here, I am saying Euro is used by multiple countries like Germany and France.

Now, while trying to fetch all the cities in one state, my following query works,

```
SELECT (
        SELECT
            ListItemID AS [value],
            ListItemCode
        FROM ListItem AS [Item]
        WHERE ListCode = 'City'
            AND (ListItemGroupID = ISNULL(2926, ListItemGroupID) OR ListItemGroupID IS NULL AND 2926 IS NULL)   
        FOR XML RAW
        )
```

But, to fetch the records from `LisItemRelationship`, I am not getting the desired result.
The query I am trying is

```
SELECT (
        SELECT
            LIR.ListItemID AS [value],
            ListItemCode
        FROM ListItem AS [Item] INNER JOIN ListItemRelationship AS LIR ON Item.ListItemID = LIR.ListItemParentID
        WHERE ListCode = 'Country'
            AND (LIR.PickListItemParentID = 2925)   
        FOR XML RAW
        )
```

I am expecting to receive following XML from 2nd query

```
<xml>
    <row value="2928" ListItemCode="Germany"/>
    <row value="2929" ListItemCode="France"/>
</xml>
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few errors in your column names. Try the following:

```sql
SELECT (
        SELECT
            LIR.ListItemID AS [value],
            Item.[Value] as ListItemCode
        FROM ListItem AS [Item]
        INNER JOIN ListItemRelationship AS LIR ON Item.ListItemID = LIR.ListItemID
        WHERE Item.ListItemCode = 'Country'
            AND (LIR.ListItemParentID = 2925)   
        FOR XML RAW
        )
```